# Polynomial $p(x)$ and $g(x)$. with $p(10)=m$ and $g(10)=n$. If, $p(x).h(x) = (\frac{p(x)}{(g(x)} - 1)(p(x) + g(x))$ and...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> > Polynomial $p(x)$ and $g(x)$. with $p(10)=m$ and $g(10)=n$. If, $p(x).h(x) = (\frac{p(x)}{(g(x)} - 1)(p(x) + g(x))$ and $h(10)=-\frac{16}{15}$. 
> >     what's the maximum of $|m + n|$ ?
> >     Edit : options are 2,0,8,6,4

my attempt

we know 
$p(x).h(x) = (\frac{p(x)}{(g(x)} - 1)(p(x) + g(x)) $

$\rightarrow p(10).h(10) = (\frac{p(10)}{(g(10)} - 1)((p(10) + g(10)) $
$\rightarrow m.-\frac{16}{15} = (\frac mn - 1)(m + n) $
$\rightarrow mn.-\frac{16}{15} = (m-n)(m + n) $
$\rightarrow m^2 - n^2 + mn\frac{16}{15}=0$

using Lagrange Multipliers
$f(m,n) = m + n -\lambda [m^2 - n^2 + mn\frac{16}{15}]$
i get complicated equations. I think i am wrong somewhere, anyone knows how to solve it in simple way, because this question supposed to be answered within minute.

Comment: Note due to the homogenous nature of the equation, for any $(m,n)$ which works, so would $(km,kn)$ for any real $k \neq 0$. This is because $k \times p(x) \times h(x) = (\frac{k \times p(x)}{k \times g(x)} - 1)(k \times p(x) + k \times g(x))$ has a factor of $k$ on each side and, thus, it simplifies to your original $p(x).h(x) = (\frac{p(x)}{g(x)} - 1)(p(x) + g(x))$. As such, there doesn't seem to be any maximum value for $|m + n|$ based on the information given in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

Your last equation can be written as

$$m^2+\frac{16}{15}nm-n^2=0$$
the discriminant is
$$\delta=\frac{64+225}{225}n^2$$
the roots are

$$m_1=-n(\frac{8}{15}+\frac{17}{15})$$

$$=-\frac{5n}{3}$$
and
$$m_2=-n(\frac{8}{15}-\frac{17}{15})$$
$$=\frac{3n}{5}$$

Comment: i am confused about how you computed the discriminant.  I thought that if $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ then the discriminant is $b^2 - 4ac.$  In your equation, this would be $\left(n\frac{16}{15}\right)^2 + 4n^2$, which is different from the discriminant that you computed.

Comment: @user2661923 You will find the same roots.

Comment: thx, i got it now. your discriminant is 1/4th of mine.

Comment: So you have allowable ratios for $m/n$, doesn’t seem to restrict in any way the value of $|m+n|$.

Comment: @Macavity Are $m$ and $n$ integers?

Comment: Nothing said in the problem, however it doesn’t matter, still it’s unbounded.

Comment: OTOH, if it was integer restricted and what was asked was the minimum, then the problem and options would make sense.